# What is the most formal way to address a respected person while referring to his name?

Tags: word-usage, email, letter-writing, salutations

I'd like to know which form is more formal and respectful to address a respected person while referring to his name.

Should I mention the person's first name instead of writing "*Sir*" for example by *Dear Sir + NAME*, or do I only write  *Dear Sir*? I am writing a formal letter to the rector and I'm looking for a way to address to him in a way that he will know that it is written especially for him.

Comment: Why not "Dear NAME"?

Comment: This might be cultural, but I would never address my rector by first name. "Dear Rector Smith", "Dear Professor Smith" or, if I don't know the name, "Dear Sir" (coming last since it is somewhat impersonal and cold). Never ever "Dear Michael", ever, unless I happened to be the rector's father, or board game buddy (and then it would not be much of a formal letter).

Comment: @Amadan If you're replying to me, I didn't say you have to use their first name...

Comment: @curiousdannii: Primarily to OP, but to you as well. FWIW, I find "Dear Smith" to also be overly familiar for the stated purpose.

Comment: You are only supposed to use *Sir* combined with first or last names for people who have been knighted (by the United Kingdom). So you can say *Dear Sir Paul McCartney,* but *Dear Sir John Doe* doesn't cut it. Either *Dear Sir* or *Dear Rector Doe* would be fine.

Comment: Better asked on Interpersonal Skills.SE.

Comment: While I understand the arguments for closing this question, I believe that they are overridden by the fact that the question already has several answers, has been seen by 62K people, and is likely to be seen many thousands more, unless its is deleted. Closing such a question (without deleting it) effectively protects the existing answers from competition, which is at odds with the underlying principle of the Stack Exchange that open competition leads to the results that are most likely to be helpful to the public at large.

Comment: Do we really write *Dear Dame Judi Dench*? Or would it be *Dear Dame Judi*?

Comment: @jsw29 Would it not be open to peer revue on the ELU site where it belongs?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, but that would be a part of an argument for migrating, rather than closing it, and the architecture of the site does not allow for migration of old questions.

Comment: Sorry to say so, and the very idea of any 'formal way to address a respected person while referring to his name' simply does not work in English. Do you truly doubt that Question belongs on SE English Language Learners, not here on Usage?

Answer (score 5):

*Dear Sir* is possibly  a little over-formal these days, but the choice between *Dear Rector, Dear Rector Smith, Dear Professor/Dr/Mr Smith/* and *Dear Egbert* will depend on the conventions in the institution in which you are studying/working. The use of the first name, unthinkable when I was at university many years ago,  is becoming more common, at least in British universities. If you are unfamiliar with the conventions in your establishment, I would suggest that *Dear Professor/Dr/Mr Smith* is reasonably safe.

Comment: The problem with using *Dear Sir* in the way in which the OP is considering using it (i.e. with a name) is not that it is 'over-formal', but that (setting aside the cases in which the person has actually been knighted) *Dear Sir* has  traditionally been used when the person's name is not known to the writer. Many people nowadays also find it objectionable because they perceive it as sexist (in so far as it may embody the assumption that the person must be male, even when there are no sufficient reasons for that assumption).

Comment: It is indeed not uncommon nowadays for university students to be on the first-name terms with those who teach them, but only if the latter have indicated that this is welcome. It would still be presumptuous for a student to use the lecturer's/professor's/rector's first name in making an initial contact with the person.

Answer (score 0):

"Dear Sir" is generally used for a person whose identity is unknown. The usual formal form of address would be "Dear Mr. ".

Comment: If the person's identity is unknown, then their gender is unknown as well. SO instead of "Dear Sir" use "Dear Sir or Madam"

Comment: @Sarah Don't do that. "To whom it may concern" or "Dear Sirs" (for an organisation) is vastly preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Please read first Debrett's Correct Form and then Burke's Peerage, either of which every search engine will instantly show you.

They will tell you exactly how to address anyone in any position and often explain why, as well.

Answer (score -5):

The most formal, respectful and deferential way of addressing a person today is **Respected Sir**, or **Respected Madam**. Use it when the other person is clearly not your equal in any way, and stands very much higher than you. Ex: your professor

Comment: http://www.formsofaddress.info/FOA_pope_catholic.html and http://www.formsofaddress.info/FOA_president_US.html

Comment: sorry @Mari-LouA, edited.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the greeting *Respected Sir (or) Madam*. I don't think I've ever come across this form of address, so I cannot upvote it but I will retract my downvote.

Comment: Most professors at least in UK or US would not expect their students to address them in this way. First name is common although you could use e.g. Prof Smith in writing.

Comment: Not in Western English, it isn't. What you Posted seems to come from straight translation of one or more Asian languages… which translations, far from working in English, serve best to show why straight translation between languages is a forlorn hope.